# Позиционирование съезжает

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, позиционирование

[image: position]

В блоке (**.result-wrapper**) у меня находится сама футболка и блок **position: relative**.   Помимо футболки в нем есть **#selming** и **.example2** с позиционированием **absolute** и они поверх футболки. 
Но, когда разрешение экрана 340px (на моб. телефонах), то **#selming** и **.example2** съезжают. Хотя размеры этих блоков меньше 340px.
Не пойму в чем дело?

```css
.result-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 475px;
}

.example2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(../blank-number.png) no-repeat;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 31px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 202px;
  height: 63px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  left: 144px;
  top: 271px;
  position: absolute;
}

#selmimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 135px;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="result-wrapper pull-left">
  <img alt="Именная футболка с номером" title="Именная футболка с номером" src="img/shirt-white.png" id="main-img" width="480">
  <div id="selmimg"><img src="logo/bmw.png" /></div>
  <div class="example2">
    <div id="region"></div>
    <div id="bukva1"></div>
    <div id="bukva2"></div>
    <div id="nomer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: relative незачем - используйте absolute, перестроить быстро. От relative может съезжать конечно, потому что это позиция со смещением - если оригинальное место элемента сместилось, сместился и элемент с relative. Я бы вообще тут не использовал absolute/relative - block/inline-block/flex вёрстка продуктивнее и гибче. Но твой код долвьше переписывать под это)

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вашей проблемы нужно выровнять блок следующим образом:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px; /* Где 100px - это половина ширины блока. */
```

Comment: Проще уже тогда `transform: translateX(-50%);`, чем харкодить половину ширины в `margin-left`.

Comment: Тот же самый эффект. Только тогда родителя придется минусовать. Ваш комментарий не имеет смысла.

Comment: а можете тогда добавить исполняемый код добавить? Тогда полезность ответа возрастёт. И я заодно наглядно увижу имеет смысл то, что я сказал или нет.